# jQuery updating value from 2 functions

Tags: jquery

Basic price of the product is 186.

Then there are 4 possibilities of shipping

And a checkbox if they want a box.
box (price+25)
nobox (price stays the same)

my code:

```
var total= 186;

$( "select#shipping" ).change(function() {
    var str = "";
    var total= 186;
    $( "select#shipping option:selected" ).each(function() {
        str += $( this ).val() + " ";
    });

    str = str.substr(1);
    total= total+ parseInt(str);
    document.getElementById("celkem").innerHTML=celkem;
}).trigger( "change" );

$('#box').change(function(){
    var c = this.checked ? 25 : -25;
    celkem = $("#total").text();
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = parseInt(total) + c;
});
```

I can't seem to get hang of it to update corectly. Now the problem is, the box checkbox is defaulty off. Lets say I select shopping #1, and then check the box. The total is 253. But when I now select #2 shipping the #box stays checked and doesnt add 25 to the total.

Can you please help me?

Comment: use radio input type instead then if 1 same price else add 25

Comment: unfortunately radio box is not really suitable here. Its much better user experience if there is just one checkbox if they want a pretty box or not. Otherwise there would have to be 2 radio buttons saying "yes i want a box" or "no i dont want a box"

Comment: If you add your HTML or create an example (codepen, jsfiddle, plunkr) it is easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to add multiple shipping numbers, then you need to parse and sum them individually like this:

```
var shippingTotal = 0;
$( "select#shipping option:selected" ).each(function() {
    shippingTotal += parseInt($( this ).val(), 10);
});
```

rather than just adding all the strings together and then trying to parse them all at once.  You can then add that shipping number to any other numbers to get the total.

It also looks like you have an issue with your total because you don't ever seem to reinitalize it, yet every time `.change()` is called you add some more to it which can't be what you want as it will just go up and up.  You don't show your HTML so it's hard for us to know exactly what you're supposed to be doing there, but the current algorithm looks like it has a problem.